# Using a range as a parameter pack

Tags: c++, variadic-functions

I have a function

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

template <typename T, typename P...> Function (T&& Sth, P&&... SthElse) {
    //Perform operations on all arguments. For example:
    std::cout << Sth << " ";
    (std::cout << ... << SthElse);
    std::cout <<"\n"; 
}
```

If I also have a vector

```
int main () {
    std::vector<int> V {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
}
```

is there some way to pass the range containing my numbers to the function as a parameter pack?
My desired structure would be something like

```
    Function(SomethingMagic(V.begin(), V.end());
```

where `SomethingMagic` turns the range into a pack to get an output in the form

```
1 2 3 4 5
```

Is there any way to convert the range in a parameter pack? Thanks in advance to anyone.

Comment: Are you asking to convert a range with runtime size and values into a compile-time parameter pack? That can't be done. Why do you think you want to do that? This seems like an X/Y question. There's probably a better way to do it. But it'll need to use runtime code constructs if it can be able to work on runtime ranges.

Comment: Hm... I didn't think of it that way... Yes, I'll need to find another way for sure

Comment: If size is know (or possible size values are limited), you might use `std::index_sequence` to construct a tuple from the vector.

Comment: @Jarod42 could you expand please?

Comment: Something like [that](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/881db340f5fbaca9).

Comment: Are you just looking for a way to do what javascript/python does with packs? If so, it doesn't work since c++ is statically typed. The idiomatic way to pass a range from a container is to pass a start and end iterator.

Comment: Use range as a range ;) Like: `template <typename  R> Function (R const& range) { for (auto const& e: range) std::cout << e; std::cout <<"\n"; }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use runtime value for compile time one.

vector size is a runtime value, size of pack is compile time.

But, if you know size at compile time, you might do something like:

```
template <typename C, std::size_t ... Is>
auto to_tuple_impl(C&& c, std::index_sequence<Is...>)
{
    return std::tie(c[Is]...);
}

template <std::size_t N, typename C>
auto to_tuple(C&& c)
{
    return to_tuple_impl(std::forward<C>(c), std::make_index_sequence<N>());
}
```

and then

```
std::apply([](auto...args){Function(args...); }, to_tuple<5>(v));
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/881db340f5fbaca9)

or

```
switch (v.size())
{
    case 5: return std::apply([](auto...args){Function(args...); }, to_tuple<5>(v));
    case 42: return std::apply([](auto...args){Function(args...); }, to_tuple<42>(v));
    // ...
    default: return; // Nothing
}
```